# Can't Make Image Move via CSS

Tags: html, css, image, layout, positioning

I'm trying to move the image for Trip Advisor on [this](http://piiholozipline.com/about/) page (at the bottom right). As seen in this screenshot, it needs to move up and to the right to fit in the orange/pink box.

[image: screenshot]

When I apply negative margin, the image gets hidden behind the orange/pink box. I've tried adding various z-index values to make it appear on-top, however nothing seems to work.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Note: This image (for Trip Advisor) is reused on the home page as well. Any CSS styling applied should not affect the positioning of the image on the home page.

Comment: Can't do anything without seeing the code... Can you post a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: z-index is used to display images above other images. This image is positioned wrong. If the place you want it inside is a div, try to put the image inside it, and add position:absolute; margin-right:15px; to the image css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem! Hope this helps.

```
.TA_rated {
  width: 155px;
  height: 77px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 265px;
  top: -6px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Edit: only tested in Safari, but should be OK elsewhere...

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. I changed the selector to .advertBlock .TA_rated to isolate the movement on this page only. So, the issue was that I was using margin-top instead of top, correct?

Comment: Awesome! As a general rule I use top/left/bottom/right properties when positioning something because, well, that's what they're for. ;)